# getting problem in add custom product attribute in PDF invoice magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I am trying to add custom attribute "publisher name" below product name in PDF invoice. Publisher is a custom attribute created by me.

I have copied

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php
```

And have added some code in `default.php` but this is not working properly. It is showing attribute id like 250,251 in the pdf but I want it to show publisher name

I add following code in default.php

```
$Publisher = $this->getPublisherValue($item);

 $lines[1][] = array(
        'text'  => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($Publisher, 35),
        'feed'  => 35
    );


private function getPublisherValue($item)
    {
        $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        if(($return_publisher = $prod->getPublisher()))
            return $return_publisher;
        else
            return 'N/A';
   }
```

Comment: what kind of attribute is publisher? is it an object or string or something else? without that I am not sure how much help we can be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we need to know what type publisher is before we can help out.

Comment: `250,251` looks like it's a `varchar` attribute with the `table` backend. Must be a multiselect due to the comma.

Comment: I appologize for a stupid question, but where I need to specify the attribute that I need to retrieve? Sorry, newbie on the subject... Thanks. I have an attribute http://imgur.com/a/Og1dP

Answer (score 1):

I guss that publisher is text type attribute

```
if($prod->getId()){
 /* if  check product is exit   */ 
 /* check getPublisher  value is null or not */
if(!is_null($prod->getPublisher()))
    return $return_publisher;
    else
    return $prod->getPublisher();



else{
return 'N/A';
}
```

If it dropdown attribute then  use below code to get publisher label

```
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('publisher')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```